# Can I Filter the Report which is Embedded in a Page and This Page comes when I click the stateless form Button?

Tags: zoho

I Have a application to process pay slip of an Employee. I have a stateless form in which I select Employee Id and salary information and when I click on the submit button then it redirects me to the page in which the actual salary information form is embedded.In this embedded page I am not able to do the filtering of selected Employee ID.
Is there any way to do filtering of selected employee ID from stateless form.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the sample application [https://creator.zoho.com/sampleapps/employees#View:Complete_Employee_details](https://creator.zoho.com/sampleapps/employees#View%3aComplete_Employee_details)

Copy that application to your account and see the script I've written.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

1. Go to the Page-Editor: Click the gear-icon in the upper-left corner to open Page-Properties

   - [Page-Properties]: In the 'Parameters' section click 'Add Parameter', a parameter field will dipsplay

     - Enter the name of one of the parameters that will be passed by the stateless form.
     - Repeat for the rest of the parameters that will be passed to the Page
     - Click 'X' in the upper-right corner to close
2. In the initial stateless-form's editing window associate the submit button with a workflow that calls openURL() and passes the values for the report to filter on (the Employee ID and salary value) to the form/report.  Example:
   `openUrl("#Page:SalaryPage?EmployeeID=" + input.EmployeeID + "&SalaryValue=" + input.SalaryValue, "same window", "MyPageTitle);`

3.In the Page put the actual-salary-information-form in a ZML-Snippet panel (or iframe) configure the zml to get use the parameters `input.EmployeeID` and `input.SalaryValue` filter the form.

These seem to be the main steps..